# extend doesn't log in because it uses role id

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

**this is my code for employee data controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Datakaryawan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class DatakaryawanController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Datakaryawan::all();
        return view('data-karyawan', ['data' => $data]);
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $data = Datakaryawan::all();
        return view('data-karyawan-add', ['data' => $data]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Datakaryawan::create($request->all());

        if ($data) {
            Session::flash('status', 'success');
            Session::flash('message', 'add new data karyawan success !');
        }
        return redirect('data-karyawan');
    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Datakaryawan::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();
        return view('data-karyawan-edit', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

**This is my main layout file for extends**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TAKA | @yield('title')</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">        
        <div class="body-content h-100">
            <div class="row g-0 h-100">
                <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 collapse d-lg-block" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                    @if (Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
                            <div class="user">
                                <a href="dashboard">{{Auth::user()->username}}</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-link">
                                <a href="data-karyawan">Data Karyawan</a>
                                <a href="daily-report">Laporan Harian</a>
                                <a href="montly-report">Laporan Bulanan</></a>
                                <a href="transection">Transaksi</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="logout">
                                <a href="logout">Logout</a>
                            </div>                        
                        @else
                            <div class="user">
                                <a href="dashboard">{{Auth::user()->username}}</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-link">
                                <a href="daily-report">Laporan Harian</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="logout">
                                <a href="logout">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="p-3 col-lg-10 content">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**before running**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcTN2.png)

**after running**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGFBI.png)

**I am using the role id that is related to the users table, while what is being a problem is the employee table which is not linked anywhere, but I want to make an edit on this employee table, using findorfail employee id, when I click on it the sidebar looks like this it's above, I don't know where the error is, because my sidebar layout uses the role id in the user table. I'm stuck on this problem because I'm still a beginner please guide me. I am using laravel version 9**

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: what is the error can u sent the error?

Comment: Please be more specific, what does "_doesn't work_" mean exactly? Blank page? No sidebar? Wrong sidebar? I don't see how the data from your method has anything to do with your sidebar or a role-id

Comment: @HasanÇetin Please see the photo because I have edited it

Comment: Nothing Laravel related. You're in a subfolder, your styles are not loaded, use `href="/css/style.css">` instead